# Tooltip Javascript Rotation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, tooltip

I have several tooltips on my website and I need to use links in one of them. So I used a short script I found online.

I want all tooltips look the same including the transition effects. I am struggling with that. The rotation and other effects applied on the tooltip with javascript are not working.

**Here is a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2baqv/2423/

`<div id="mouseon-examples">
    <div><ul><li><a href="xx">Not working tooltip</a></li></ul></div>

    </div>
<nav class="templatemo-top-nav">
     <ul><li><a href="xy">Working Tooltip<span>TEXT IN TOOLTIP</span></a></li></ul>
     </nav>`

Could you please help me with it? Do I have any errori in the code? Is there any way how to do exactly same transition in script code?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2baqv/2424/)?

```
Changed javascript selector to class since html doesn't like same ID's
```

Comment: The script is not working then. You posted a code with two working links. The old one wtill wouldn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/rqywukjs/ It behaves weirdly

Comment: With 2 working links? not sure if i fully understand what you're trying to achieve, just change the link of one of the tooltips and they link differendly

Comment: In your example I am not able to click on the link because as I cannot hover over it. The script should manage that the link is clickable and the tooltip stays shown after hovering

Comment: You're using a plugin, try to tweak a little bit in there, like when it says: on mouseover -> show tooltip you can put a delay on it for example.

Comment: Nope, sorry but you did not understand me or the script. Please look at my example and compare it with yours. You are showing only text in the tooltip, I am doing it as well in my example. The problem is with showing a link. I cannot use <span> for showing the link. And that's the problem. This version works closest to my desired result. http://jsfiddle.net/rqywukjs/1/ Still not perfect. I don't know which element to use with :hover in css. That might be the problem :-(